# Could not decode token: The token ###

Tags: json, swift, laravel, token, jwt

I'm using Laravel 5.3 as an API for my iOS app. When I try to make HTTP calls with headers and parameters I get this 401 error:

> message = "Could not decode token: The token
>   \"Optional(\""eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhcL3Bvc3RMb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTQ4MDUzNzQxOCwiZXhwIjoxNDgwNTQxMDE4LCJuYmYiOjE0ODA1Mzc0MTgsImp0aSI6ImMyZmYxNzI5N2U5OGU4MzkzYzZkZWRmNTZlN2ZkMzNkIn0.u6sQqlq5k-B5jhZ7EymkXLlcTIQ-i7X_83an5irwTss\"" is an
>   invalid JWS";
>       "status_code" = 401; }

This is the code that makes the HTTP request:

```
let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"]

    request(url! ,  method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default ,  headers: headers )
        .responseJSON { response in


        print("RESPONSE \(response)")
```

I did some googling and found a package to encode JWT called JWTDecode.swift. Here is the link to the code: https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.swift. I still couldn't figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: In the error message the token is an Optional and hasn't been unwrapped, it may be the reason.

Comment: I'm saving the token in a container like this ` var token: String? {
        didSet {
            
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(token, forKey:DefaultsKey.token)
        }
        
` and then calling it in the header array `let headers = ["Authorization" : "Bearer\(UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token)"]n` where should I unwrap it?

Comment: It looks like user simpleBob has made a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"]
```

to something like

```
guard let token = token else { return }
let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"]
```

otherwise you are sending `Optional(<token>)` instead of `<token>`.

Comment: you mean like this  `guard let token = UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token else { return nil }
let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"]` because the token is saved in nsuserdefaults

Comment: Exactly, if you are in a function that should return `nil` if you don't have a token.

Comment: error `unexpected non void return value in void function `

Comment: updated the answer, you should not return `nil`, you should just return

Comment: thankss it solved the problem!! but why in my database it's saved  with `Optional("hello")`? Do I have to go over the parameters and do `guard let`to unwarp them ?

Comment: you probably saved it with an optional, you have to unwrap it as well (adding a `if let`, `guard let` or `!`)